# Change tr background color when img inside td is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

well i am filling a table with php with values from DB

what i was trying to but unsuccessful didnt is to change the tr background color when image is clicked

here is what i tried to do

```
<script>
 function changeColor(tr)
 {
   var tableRow = document.getElementById(tr);
   tableRow.style.backgroundColor='red';
 }
</script>

<html>
      <table>
            <tr id='tr<?php echo $personID;?>'>
                  <td>
                      <?php echo $personName;?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <?php echo $personLastName;?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <img src= "/*an image*/" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('tr<?php echo $personID;?>')" >
                  </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
</html>
```

obiously this is just for one case but when i get elements from DB this table is pretty long
any ideas?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

one more thing

my table already has an css design where

```
td
{
 background: #EDEDED;
}
tr:hover
{ 
 background: #d0dafd;
}
```

this is maybe why when doing `onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.background='gray'"`

is not working how can i fix this?

Comment: Is this the actual code, or separate piece of it?  You have a script outside of the HTML tag, no <head> or <body> tag.  If it's just pieces that's fine though

Comment: you're right, didn't notice that, but you are correct  the script is inside the html tag

Comment: Did you want the row to stay red even when you click on the next image?  Also, if you click a second time should it go back to normal?  I can update my answer if that's the case.

Comment: Instead of directly setting the color, add a class 'highlight' or something similar using jQuery.  Then, when the hover ends, the class will live on and the change in style will persist.

Comment: @jqueryrocks if it is clicked  is goes red doesn't matter if  it is clicked again, but i forgot  something my table already has a css style and i think that is complicating  things for me

Comment: updated code below - rename the :hover style to .hoverStyle and make a .highlight CSS class and my answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use parentNode : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/psHjh)**

```
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50"
       onmouseover="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.background='gray'" 
       onmouseout="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.background=''"
  />
```

img->parentNode=td -> parentNode=tr

Comment: the post said he wanted to change the color when the image was clicked, not on mouseover

Comment: @GCyrillus this codes work perfectly if td doesnt have already a background color and `onmouseover` is changed by `onclick` thanks but it is not working for me

Comment: the good practice is usually to add/remove a class instead updating style values

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code

```
//code for clicks
$('td img').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('table').children('tr').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
});

//code for hovering
$('tr').hover(function() {
  //if the tr has the highlight class do nothing, otherwise add hover style
  if(!$(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
    $(this).addClass('hoverStyle');
  } 
}, function() {
  //if the tr has hover style remove it when hover ends
  if($(this).hasClass('hoverStyle')) {
    $(this).removeClass('hoverStyle');
  }
});
```

Then just make a CSS class to define the highlight style.

Comment: using `parents` with a note that if we have nested tables, should the behavior be applied also to the outside table (or just the inner one or just the outside table)? In case the behavior should be applied only on the inside table, you can use `closest('table')` instead.